# Factory_girl create gives validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test a destroy action in my rails application. I use Factory_girl to create objects.
When creating a company object it's mandatory to add a user relation. But this is where I get a fail when I try to create a Company with Factory_girl.

user_spec.rb

```
describe User do

  before(:each) { @user = User.new(email: 'user@example.com') }

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:companies) }

  it "#email returns a string" do
    expect(@user.email).to match 'user@example.com'
  end

  describe "company associations" do 
    let!(:a_company) do
      FactoryGirl.create(:company, user: @user)
    end

   it {should have_many :companies, :dependent => :destroy}
  end

end
```

factory.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    confirmed_at Time.now
    name "Test User"
    email "test@example.com"
    password "please123"

    trait :admin do
      role 'admin'
    end
  end   
  factory :company do
    name "Total Inc."
    user :user 
  end
end
```

model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies, dependent: :destroy
  enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

model/company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

The error I get:

Failures:

```
  1) User company associations
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:company, user: @user)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: User can't be blank
```

**EDIT**

I followed the advise from below and now I can create but get following error:

```
Failure/Error: it {should have_many :companies, :dependent => :destroy} expected #<User:0x007fc7b7ce08c0> to respond to has_many?
```

Comment: `@user` always `nil` you should use `create` instead `new` in `before(:each)` block. Company never create because `@user` always `nil`.

Comment: Try using `let` instead of `let!`

Comment: In your company factory it should be just `user` rather than `user :user`

Comment: @BroiSatse this maybe problems too, but `User.new.id == nil` and Company do not created, validation `:user_id` presence fails.

Comment: @BroiSatse changing to let just gives Failure/Error: it {should have_many :companies, :dependent => :destroy}
       expected #<User:0x007fc7b7ce08c0> to respond to `has_many?`

Comment: @Зелёный change to create doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @TomKadwill doesn't change a thing.Still have an error...

Comment: @Зелёный should I create companies? How do I do that?

Comment: @gtheys should be `it { should have_many(:companies).dependent(:destroy) }` [look carefully doc](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb#L331)

Comment: @Зелёный tried it like that: undefined method `dependent' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Has:0x007fc7381583b0>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error, `Validation failed: User can't be blank`, is a result of not having saved the `@user` object. You can fix the error by saving the object before you call create:

```
let!(:a_company) do
  @user.save
  FactoryGirl.create(:company, user: @user)
end
```

The second error, `Failure/Error: it {should have_many :companies, :dependent => :destroy} expected #<User:0x007fc7b7ce08c0> to respond to has_many?` is a testing error - the production code works fine. To fix your test try one of the following options:

**Use [Shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda)**

```
it {should have_many(:companies).dependent(:destroy)}
```

**Use FactoryGirl**

```
it 'Expects user to have many companies' do
  expect{@user.companies}.to_not raise_error
end
```

Comment: Using the create instead of the new already solved the `Validation failed: User can't be blank`. For testing the shoulda option gives `undefined method 'dependent' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Has:0x007fc7381583b0>`, using factory girl with expect works :) Now I just want to know why the shoulda gives the undefined method error?

Comment: Have you added `gem 'shoulda'` to your Gemfile and bundled? The error message implied that you don't have shoulda installed

Comment: Indeed forgot to install :D